# XP can't ping Windows 7 virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualization, virtual-machine

I have Windows 7 installed on my PC and I installed Microsoft Virtual Machine 2007 and installed Windows XP SP1 on it.

I want the two OS's to see each other but they can't ping each other.

I selected the NAT networking so I can check the web but yet can't ping.

so what's wrong?

Comment: That's correct. When you use NAT you can't directly access the VMs from the network.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason otherwise, I'd use bridge networking. Double-natting does some weird stuff sometimes. Then you might be able to ping. Also bridging makes the VM appear as if it were on your local network, allowing easier communication between workstations.

Also check firewall settings on the VM and host machines.